# Mixed-effects modelling with GLMMadaptive for multiply-left-censored data in R

Tags: r, mixed-models

I have a dataset of environmental pollutants measured above or below some instrument threshold. Instruments and pollutants have changed through time and so the threshold has moved around within the dataset. Secondly, multiple pollutants were measured for each sample, so there is some non-independence in the measurements.

First, is anyone aware of what R packages exist for modelling a dataset such as this? I have tried the `NADA` package, but this doesn't support mixed-effects, or multiple censoring levels in regressions. I have looked into the `VGAM` package which supports multiple censoring levels in tobit analysis via the vector generalized linear model function but not mixed effects.

Next, it seems like the `GLMMadaptive` package has some facilities to analyse my data but I'm not able to locate informative help pages for the questions I am asking, namely, if it is possible/how to specify the censoring level in the `censored.normal()` family function.

Am I missing something in the packages named above or is `GLMMadaptive` the way to go? If so, how can I specify which observations are censored and what the censoring level is? This is what the model looks like:

```
mixed_model(fixed = Result ~ Sample_type/AG_level/Regulated,
            random = ~1|Sample_ID, data = pollutants,
            family = censored.normal()) ### no argument for censoring-levels in the documentation
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The [Mixed Models task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MixedModels.html) says: "Censored data (response data known only up to lower/upper bounds): brms and nlmixr2 (general), ARpLMEC (censored Gaussian, autoregressive errors). Censored Gaussian (Tobit) responses: GLMMadaptive, MCMCglmm, gamlss."

Comment: Thanks Ben, I was not aware of that task view resource. Extremely useful -- brms does the job. I will accept this answer if you post it. The equivalent model formulation (except now using a more appropriate lognormal error distribution) with brms is `brm(Result | cens(Censored) ~ Compound + Sample_type/AG_level/Regulated + (1|Sample_ID), data = pollutants, family = lognormal())`

Comment: You're welcome to post the answer yourself (including the information from both comments, i.e. both the task view link/info and your final model) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Dr. Bolker and this very useful [Task View resource](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MixedModels.html) for various modelling resources in R, the `brms` package was determined to be the tool for this job. To fit a Bayesian model to the data described above, the `brm` function call looks like this:

```
mod1 <- brm(Result | cens(Censored) ~ Compound + Sample_type/AG_level/Regulated + (1|ID),
            data = pollutants,
            family = lognormal(), chains=4, cores=4)
```

with a couple of notable tweaks to the attempt in the question. First, the error distribution is log-normal, which may be more appropriate for the situation that was described. Some other error distribution could easily be specified. Secondly, the `cens()` function, as explained in the `brms` help files is an indicator in the `pollutants` data frame for each observation for (left in this case, though there are other options) censored chemistry results.

Otherwise, the mixed effects model specifications are in the familiar R-formula format. Works like a charm.